# Backbone.js detect a PUT, POST, GET, DELETE, PATCH during parse

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js

This is overall a specific question, but generally I'd like to know if all possibilities are in fact possibilities.

Currently I am trying to "detect" in a matter of speaking the PUT/POST from a `.save()` action when the model/collection runs it's `parse` function. The primary use case for me is when the user triggers a save I want to display a "Success" or "Error" message respectively. but only when saving ie PUT or POST. However everything I tried shows either message even when fetching the data initially.

Anyone know how to treat this appropriately without hacking into backbones methods?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you're trying to achieve and where? You want to detect PUT/POST in `save`? When `parse` comes into play? Could you post a pseudo-code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the use-case for not doing something like:

```
onSaveEvent:
    this.model.save().done(..).fail(..)
```

(because you tend to know that the model is there already and therefore it will be a put or patch)

Anyway `save` calls `sync` with a `method` string as first arg:

```
var methodMap = {
    'create': 'POST', <-- this
    'update': 'PUT',  <-- this
    'patch':  'PATCH',  <-- this
    'delete': 'DELETE',
    'read':   'GET'
};
```

It will only do a POST if the model is new (it has no id). Backbone uses the `isNew` method for that, so:

```
if (!model.isNew()) {
  // it's one you're interested in
}
```

Did that answer your question or did I misunderstand?